# Using IN on a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to use LINQ on a list inside an object. I'll try to explain:

I've got an object called "Comment".
In the comment object I have a list of "User" objects, where each user object has an "ID" field.

such as

```
Public class Comment {
List<User> users;
...
}
```

Then, I get a list of user ids (let's call it UsersList, such as UsersList is a List< int > object) and would like to get all comments where all users in the UsersList are in the "users" list of that comment.

So if `UsersList = {1,2}` I would like to get all comments where the user with an id of 1 and the user with an id of 2 will be present in the "users" list.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query it the other way round, i.e. instead of asking "userId in listOfIds", ask "listOfIds.Contains(userId)".

```
var query = comments
    .Where(c => UsersList.All(id => c.users.Any(u => u.ID == id)));
```

Comment: This works, but only to give if ONE of the userid is present, and not both in the same time. But still is a good start :) Thanks

Comment: Ok, I exchanged the `Any` by `All`.

Comment: Well, it still doesn't work - if you work out the logic, you'll see that what it actually does it looks for comments where the users lists are the same. i.e - that c.users is exactly the same as UsersList. Still working on solving it :)

Comment: Well, not exactly that :) It happens that if the c.users contains more users than in UsersList it will not return it. But if it contains only part of UsersList - it will return it.

Comment: I changed my answer again and am basically getting the same answer as JotaBe now. I am returning all comments where all the users of the id-list are present in the user list of a comment. The comment may have more users in its list however.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you :) Just had to change 'Contains' to 'Any' because it can't accept lambda expressions. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Changed it again. It appears that this was the solution proposed by Cuong Le.

Answer (score 3):

```
comments.Where(c => usersList.All(id => c.users.Any(user => user.Id == id)));
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this:

```
comments.Where(c => UsersList.All(uId => c.users.Contains(u => u.Id == uId)));
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. The Comment object doesn't have a UserId property. It has a list of users where each on of them has the UserId property.